# Is there a way to optimize SpaCy training?

Tags: python, performance, machine-learning, spacy

I'm currently training a SpaCy model for multi-label text classification. There are 6 labels: anger, anticipation, disgust, fear, joy, sadness, surprise and trust. The dataset is over 200k. However, per epoch is taking 4 hours. I was wondering if there's a way to optimize the training and do it faster, maybe I'm skipping something here that can improve the model.

---

**TRAINING_DATA**

```py
TRAIN_DATA = list(zip(train_texts, [{"cats": cats} for cats in final_train_cats]))

[...
  {'cats': {'anger': 1,
    'anticipation': 0,
    'disgust': 0,
    'fear': 0,
    'joy': 0,
    'sadness': 0,
    'surprise': 0,
    'trust': 0}}),
 ('mausoleum',
  {'cats': {'anger': 1,
    'anticipation': 0,
    'disgust': 0,
    'fear': 0,
    'joy': 0,
    'sadness': 0,
    'surprise': 0,
    'trust': 0}}),
 ...]
```

**TRAINING**

```py
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
category = nlp.create_pipe("textcat", config={"exclusive_classes": True})
nlp.add_pipe(category)

# add label to text classifier
category.add_label("trust")
category.add_label("fear")
category.add_label("disgust")
category.add_label("surprise")
category.add_label("anticipation")
category.add_label("anger")
category.add_label("joy")

optimizer = nlp.begin_training()
losses = {}

for i in range(100):
    random.shuffle(TRAIN_DATA)

    print('...')
    for batch in minibatch(TRAIN_DATA, size=8):
        texts = [nlp(text) for text, entities in batch]
        annotations = [{"cats": entities} for text, entities in batch]
        nlp.update(texts, annotations, sgd=optimizer, losses=losses)
    print(i, losses)

...
0 {'parser': 0.0, 'tagger': 27.018985521040854, 'textcat': 0.0, 'ner': 0.0}
...
1 {'parser': 0.0, 'tagger': 27.01898552104131, 'textcat': 0.0, 'ner': 0.0}
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"200k-record dataset is taking 4 hours per-epoch" doesn't tell us much:

1. Make sure you're not blowing out memory (are you?) How much RAM is it taking?
2. **You are presumably running single-thread, due to the GIL**. See e.g. [this](https://medium.com/@vishnups/speeding-up-spacy-f766e3dd033c) on how to turn off the GIL to run training multicore. How many cores do you have?

- **putting `texts = [nlp(text) ...]` inside your inner-loop `for batch in minibatch(TRAIN_DATA, size=8):` looks like trouble, because your code will always hold the GIL, even though you only need it for C-library string calls on processing the input text i.e. the `parser` stage, not for training.**
- Refactor your code so you first run `nlp()` pipeline on all your input, then save some intermediate representation (array or whatever). Keep that code separate to your training loop, so training can be multithreaded.

3. I can't comment on your choice of `minibatch()` parameters, but 8 seems very small, and those parameters seem to matter for performance, so try tweaking them (/grid-search a few values).
4. Finally, once you first check all of the above, find the fastest unicore/multicore box you can, and with enough RAM.

Comment: I'm using google colab pro, (25 gb RAM). Where do you suggest to use `text = [nlp(text)...` Can you edit your comment with your current suggestions? I already updated the size of the minibach and have an improvement

Comment: Sorry this is the best I can say, not familiar with the syntax, but glad to hear you mde progress.